# Process Builder Transition To Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder

I want to investigate one of my processes created via process builder but when i download it as metadata it ends with .flow that means every old processes created via process builder is now kept as .flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, historically, Process Builder metadata was represented with the [Flow Metadata Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm?q=flow)

When Flows were added, they too use the Flow Metadata Type. In fact, the `Flow` metadata type is used for lots of things including Login Flows, Orchestrator, Surveys, and more

Thus, while the underlying metadata type is the same, the Process Builder functionality as surfaced via `Setup | Process Builder` is deprecated and orgs are encouraged to migrate to Lightning Flow